# Does Google prefer HTML sitemaps or XML sitemaps? And does it hurt to implement both?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, web-crawlers

I just read that Google prefers HTML sitemaps. We have so far, only implemented an XML sitemap.

Would it hurt to add an HTML sitemap, and not remove the XML sitemap?

Also, can you submit the HTML sitemap to Google via the Search Console, or is that reserved only for XML sitemaps?

Answer (score 1):

HTML sitemaps are primarily for users however, search bots may also use it just like they use any other page with links. XML (or txt) sitemaps are for search bots only where you can tell lot of other things (like last update etc) to bots apart from plain links.

So, it is best to have both as they are for different purposes.

I think, you can submit only xml or txt (list of links in a plain text file) in google search console.